# how to ensure consistent database update under race condition using flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

This might be an old question. But I am new to database and flask-sqlalchemy and could not find any answers from previous posts. Maybe the answer is quite simple.

I am trying to deploy a Flask app to Heroku using postgresql. It has the following model, which is an inventory tracking how many items left in stock.

```
class Inventory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'inventories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    count = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

There is a web form where users use to place an order which will update the number of items left in the database tracked by field **count**. The code below handles the order and sets different status depending if there are enough items left.

```
item = Inventory.query.filter_by(name=form.name.data).first()
order = int(form.count.data)
if item.count > order:
    item.count -= order
    db.session.add(item)
    db.session.commit()
    status = ('%r: %d left' % (item.name, item.count))
else:
    status = '%r not enough left' % item.name
```

If user1 and user2 place orders on the same item simultaneously and there are 5 items left. Maybe user1's request arrives first with 3 orders. Then when user2's request arrives, user1's order may not have been committed yet. So user2 also sees 5 items left. So in the end, items left in the database is 2; both user1 and user2 successfully place their orders of 3 items for each user, though there are only 5 items left at the beginning, which is eough. How can this issue be avoided?

[This image explains the above situation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3xHN.png)

Answer (score 3):

To prevent stale data from leaking into the database, you need to perform an atomic update.

```
item.count = Item.count - order
```

You'll still have to check for and handle negative quantities after you commit the session.

This can be as simple as

```
db.session.commit()

if item.count < 0:
  # roll back the order
```

When you commit a session, SQLAlchemy clears its internal cache and will reload records from the database.

Comment: If there are 5 items left, user1 orders 3 item and user2 also orders 3 item, the number of items left might become 2 in the end. How to prevent this or check this after the session is committed? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain it a little bit more? when you do the initial query for the item, it may return 5 for both user1 and user2 since user1's request is not committed yet.

Comment: My code checks the quantity *after* updating the database. The original value never matters.

Comment: your code checks negative quantity only. If the quantity is positive, it breaks, right? item = Inventory.query.filter_by(name=form.name.data).first() may gives item.count = 5 for both user1 and user2. Then after commit, item.count will be 2. So both users1 and user2 are able to order 3 items, which is incorrect.

Comment: If the quantity is positive it does nothing since you were able to satisfy the order.

Comment: No, my point is that the original query item = Inventory.query.filter_by(name=form.name.data).first() may not be correct since user1 may not have committed yet. Then the query got by user2 is incorrect.

Comment: Although the OP didn't understand, thanks for the answer @dirn, I didn't know about the atomic update operation in SQL Alchemy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete code example for @dirn's answer

```
item = Inventory.query.filter_by(name=form.name.data).first()
order = int(form.count.data)
item.count = Item.count - order
db.session.commit()

if item.count < 0:
    status = '%r not enough left' % item.name

    # Should rollback/cancel the order
    ...

else:
    status = ('%r: %d left' % (item.name, item.count))
```